# Error en el $match del metodo .aggregate en mongo

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo una api en node la cual tiene un método de búsqueda a través de unos parámetros query (year, zone).

Este método hace agrupa transacciones por ID de clientes y hace una pequeña suma.

`Year` es obligatorio, pero `zone` es opcional.

El problema está en que cuando `zone` viene vacío desde la request, la consulta no funciona. El método no devuelve nada.
Debería de volver resultados ignorando la variable como hace el método .find()

pd: si existe req.query.zone por lo tanto existe `zone` si devuelve correctamte la consulta

```
const documents = await collection.aggregate([{
        $match: {
          'year': year,
          'zone': zone
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$customer_id',
          sales_price: {$sum: '$sales_price'},
        }
      }
    ]).toArray();
```

gracias

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que la consulta regresa resultados cuando `zone` no tiene nada? Se me ocurre que tal vez no hay registros que cumplan esa condición en la colección, pues mongoDB no te esta mostrando mensajes de error. ¿Puedes verificar que si existen registros que cumplan con esta condición de `zone`(null,undefined,empty)? ¿Que tipo de dato es `zone`? Saludos

Comment: Un `consoel.log(documents.length)` para ver si llega algo desde node, si tienes acceso a la BDD desde el shell, revisa tu `aggregation` directamente pasándole los valores duros, haber que resulta.

Comment: Solo para dejar claro mi argumento, verifica que haya registros para las condiciones: `year:cualquier año`y `zone:`, tal vez no hay registros para algún año en particular, o para cualquier año.

Comment: `zone` es tipo string (Equivale a una zona y siempre hay un valor). He probado lo de la shell y claro no existe ningún registro con `zone` (null, undefined, empty) por eso no regresa nada. La cuestión es que cuando el zone no esta. Debería devolver todos los valores con year (Sin tomar) en cuenta la  zone. (como hace el método find())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

En la solicitud (`request`) el parámetro para `zone` es opcional, es decir puede venir definido o no, entonces el objeto que estás pasando a la etapa `$match` tendrá el campo `zone` como `undefined` cuando el mismo no está definido en la solicitud. Eso hace que ningún documento de tu colección coincida con los valores pasados en el objeto cuyo campo `zone` sea `undefined`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debes construir el objeto de filtro de forma dinámica. Por ejemplo:

```js
// iniciamos un objeto de filtro vacío
let filtro = {};

if(req.query.year) {
// o tal vez req.body o req.params depende como envíes la solicitud
  filtro["year"] = req.query.year;
}

if(req.query.zone) {
  filtro["zone"] = req.query.zone;
}

// Ahora filtro tendrá los valores adecuados sólo si los mismos cumplen
// las condiciones básicas antes mostradas (distintos de null, undefined, false y "").
// Ya podemos pasar el objeto a nuestra agregación:
const documents = await collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: filtro
  },
  // resto de la agregación
]);
```

Como se observa en el código, se construye el objeto de filtro a partir de los posibles valores para `year` y `zone`. Si alguno de ellos no estuviera presente en la solicitud, simplemente no estará presente en el filtro.

En el siguiente `snippet` se ve el resultado:

```js
const params = [{year: "2020", zone: "Barcelona"}, {}, {year: "2021"}, {zone: "Madrid"}, {year: "", zone: "Valencia"}, {year: "2021", zone: ""}];

params.forEach(param => {
  let filtro = {};
  if(param.year) {
    filtro["year"] = param.year;
  }
  
  if(param.zone) {
    filtro["zone"] = param.zone;
  }

  console.log(filtro);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.